# Parsing XML in Windows Phone using C#

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone

I'm doing an app in Windows Phone and trying to parse XML that looks like this:

```
    <book>
        <chapter no="1">
            <title> X </title> 
            <activity no = "1"> A </activity>
            <activity no = "2"> B </activity>
        </chapter>
        <chapter no="2">
            <title> Y </title> 
            <activity no = "1"> C </activity>
            <activity no = "2"> D </activity>
        </chapter>
        <chapter no="3">
            <title> Z </title> 
            <activity no = "1"> E </activity>
            <activity no = "2"> F </activity>
        </chapter>
    </book>
```

Say I want to put C and D in a Listbox such that it looks like this:

```
1 C
2 D
```

My code right now looks like this

```
    var x = XElement.Load("Data/Book.xml");
    listBox1.ItemsSource = from xml in x.Descendants("chapter")
                           where (string)xml.Attribute("no") == "2"
                           select new Item
                           {
                               ActivityNo = xml.Element("activity").
                                   Attribute("no").Value,
                               Activity = xml.Element("activity").Value,
                               };
```

With my code however, it only returns the first instance of `<activity>`.  If I remove the line "where (string)xml.Attribute("no") == "2"", A, C, and E are returned.

Anything I am missing?  Admittedly, it's not might first time working on XML but I've been stuck for hours.  XML structuring is not my forte though, and any suggestions on making the XML file would also be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the actual XML has quotes.  Edited my question to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the `activity` descendants of the node and use that to create your items:

```
var items = from xml in x.Descendants("chapter")
            where (string)xml.Attribute("no") == "2"
            from act in xml.Descendants("activity")
            select new Item
            {
                ActivityNo = act.
                    Attribute("no").Value,
                Activity = act.Value,
            };
```

Comment: It worked!  Thank you, I didn't know you could do multiple "from" statements.  It seems I must practice XML parsing more.  Or should I restructure my XML better?

Comment: @CCCC I don't think it is a problem with your XML, as long as the structure matches your data layout. The multiple from syntax is a LINQ concept, so it will work with any nested data types.